# How to diagnose slow network connections with 18.04 on Dell XPS 7590?

Tags: networking, wireless, internet, dell

I've recently started having a mysterious networking issue: network connections are slow and frequently time out.

This manifests as Spotify thinking it's offline, webpages timing out or being incredibly slow to load, or network utilities like `speedtest-cli` timing out. But at the same time, `ping` shows fast, consistent successes, and running a speed test on Okla - while slow to load the page initially - shows respectable 80down/30up speeds.

The issue only appeared recently. After installing Ubuntu, I installed the missing wifi driver for this machine's wifi card with few problems. Everything worked as expected for months.

Specs:

- Machine: Dell XPS 9570
- Installation: 18.04.4
- Wifi card: `lspci -nn` shows `3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)`

Potential culprits investigated:

- AppArmor - I've put everything back in to "learning" mode.
- Router/network - this machine has the problem on multiple networks, while other devices have no problem.
- DNS - this should have been unchanged, but I switched to Google/Cloudflare. No difference.
- Firmware updates distributed by Canonical - I've been installing these all along, but hadn't installed one immediately prior to this problem appearing.
- MTU/packet fragmentation - the problem persists with lower MTU set (1492, 1472, 1200). And I don't see packet fragmentation testing `ping` with packetsize 1472 (1500 - 28 bytes for headers).

Questions:

1. Has anyone encountered a problem like this before? Able to connect to the network, but with degraded performance?
2. What tools should I be using to diagnose the source of the problem? I don't see anything remarkable in `tcpdump`, but I don't know that I'd notice if something were wrong. What tests can I perform? Where else should I be looking?

Comment: Read `man ip`. Check your MTU. WiFi MTU should be 1492, not 1500.

Comment: Good idea. Checked this, not getting packet fragmentation testing 1500 byte frames with `ping -s $((1500 - 28)) -M do google.com -c 1`.
Set MTU to 1492 anyway just to check, and problem persists with MTU set to 1492. Will add to question, thanks.

Comment: Look at the logs for networking: `sudo journalctl  -b 0 /usr/bin/NetworkManager`. Also, install and run `tracepath`.